# Form won't validate when using WTForms' SelectMultipleField

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form that I created with WTForms (using the Flask-WTF extension) and am using a SelectMultipleField to generate two groups of dynamic checkboxes. I'm having an issue where if I check any of the boxes from the Orientation group the form does not validate, but also does not give me any validation errors. I'm also not using any validators on that field. If I submit it without checking anything from the Orientation group, it will submit just fine. If I select any of the checkboxes from the Subreddit group, which is built almost identically, the form submits just fine.

Here is my form class:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required(), Length(1,64),
                                             Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[
        Required(), Length(1, 64), Regexp('^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*$', 0,
                                          'Usernames must have only letters, '
                                          'numbers, dots or underscores')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[
        Required(), EqualTo('password2', message='Passwords must match.')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[Required()])
    sex = SelectField('Sex', choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('T', 'Transgendered')], validators=[Required()])
    min_age = IntegerField('Minimum Age', validators=[Required()])
    max_age = IntegerField('Maximum Age', validators=[Required()])
    city = StringField('City', validators=[Required()])
    state = SelectField('State', validators=[Required()])
    location_alias = StringField('Location Aliases')
    location_radius = IntegerField('Radius of matches (in miles)',
                                    validators=[Required(), NumberRange(min=0,
                                                         max=100,
                                                         message="Radius must be between 0-100 miles.")])
    orientation = SelectMultipleField('Orientation (posts you want to see)',
                                      option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                      widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    subreddits = SelectMultipleField('Subreddits',
                                     option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                     widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))

    def validate_min_age(self, field):
        if field.data < 18:
            raise ValidationError("Minimum age must be at least 18.")

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError("We already have a user with this email address.")

    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError("We already have a user with this username.")

    # Data for dynamic checkboxes needs to be initialized when the form is used
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state.choices = [(s.state, s.state) for s in State.query.all()]
        self.orientation.choices = [(o.orientation, o.orientation) for o in Orientation.query.all()]
        self.subreddits.choices = [(s.subreddit, s.subreddit) for s in Subreddit.query.all()]
```

And here is my view that loads this form and calls `validate_on_submit()`:

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # get or create the location object
        l = Location.query.filter_by(city=form.city.data, state=form.state.data).first()
        if not l:
            l = Location(city=form.city.data, state=form.state.data)
            db.session.add(l)
            db.session.commit()

        # add the locaton alias
        for location_alias in form.location_alias.data.split('*'):
            if location_alias:
                add_location_alias(l, location_alias)

        # get the orientations
        orientations = []
        for o in form.orientation.data:
            orientation = Orientation.query.filter_by(orientation=o).first()
            if orientation:
                orientations.append(orientation)

        # add the user
        u = User(
            email=form.email.data,
            username=form.username.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            sex=form.sex.data,
            min_age=form.min_age.data,
            max_age=form.max_age.data,
            location_id=l.id,
            location_radius=form.location_radius.data,
            orientations=orientations,
            subreddits=[]

        )
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
        print 'User has been added successfully.'
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    print 'Form failed validation.'
    return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form)
```